# Files requested from Cloudfront aren't cached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, browser-cache, amazon-cloudfront

I've setup AWS Cloudfront successfully (I think). And by successfully I mean that I get stuff from cloudfront.

I noticed that things aren't getting cached up by the browser, and everything is redownloaded.

I added   `config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=#{1.year.to_i}"` to production.rb
but didn't help

I am using Heroku, Rails 4.0.4, paperclip and asset_sync

Did I miss anything in the configuration? or anything went wrong?

This is the request headers

```
GET /users/avatars/me.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: assets.mydomain.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://mydomain.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
```

and response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 18394
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 24 Apr 2014 14:16:40 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 09 Mar 2014 21:17:09 GMT
ETag: "a81f57bc65cea2535w75aa94c334d"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Age: 2157
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 96cb60390320349823485f0fb38.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: gceHbzsluASDFvraASFvalerhgy_GY3nP0Qaa7iPY1ug==
```

and for an asset

request:

```
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:d36kdk9v8wr6hu.cloudfront.net
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://mydomain.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
```

response headers

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:2315
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31557600
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:34412
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Thu, 24 Apr 2014 14:16:40 GMT
ETag:"795ae17b75612313b5ce5ecf1a14cd8"
Expires:Fri, 24 Apr 2015 20:12:58 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 24 Apr 2014 14:12:59 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Via:1.1 96cb60390320349823485f0fb38.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:SkbZJTSD5PAPnawlerszlsdfnzIOqJROA4LegMgBIPcU1aN0T08sdUA==
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront
```

Comment: How are you determining that the content isn't being cached?  Your cache control headers look fine.

Comment: hmm, so maybe I am confused.. shouldn't chrome inspect > network show under each request if it is fetched from cache or not in the size column? Right now every asset or image shows its size and not cache.. Does that mean anything?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Open your S3 bucket which is the source of your CloudFront distribution, and locate the files you want to cache. Then under Properties > Metadata set a Cache-Control key with a vaule of max-age=x you want.

Hope this helps!

[image]